# CakeEmail response of mail send

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can successfully send emails by using **[CakeEmail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html)** class of CakePHP.
But how can I be sure that the email is sent ?
Does a response comes when email is sent successfully?

When i take success response, I will redirect visitor to some other page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[send()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/cake-email#method-CakeEmailsend)** method send the content array if the mail send successfully or it throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you i catch that exception now. Additional info:                                              try {
            $email->send($fullMessage);
  } catch (SocketException $e) {
            debug($e->getMessage());
  }